# RequireJS load dynamic dependencies as variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Is there a way load class names as variables? `new window[a]` does not seem to work. I'm getting an error of `TypeError: window[a] is not a constructor`.

```
require([
    'myController'
], function (myController) {
    // this is working fine
    // new myController().init();

    $(function() {
        var a = $('.test').attr('class'); // this returns myController
        new window[a]; // error here
    });
});
```

Comment: What's in `window[a]` are you storing class names as properties in the global scope? Like, if `window[a]` has the string `"Foo"`, you want to run `new Foo()`?

Comment: Yup, you got it right.

Answer (score -1):

To do what you want you would need to use `eval` like this:

```
eval("new " + window[a] + "()");
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ybjo4pn9/

---

**NOTE:** [Use `eval` with caution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

Comment: Perhaps it was that using eval() is dangerous. But sometimes it's the best way to solve a problem. There's a lengthy discussion here: "When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?" -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: That's the only reason I can think of. But I gave an unbiased answer for how to solve this particular problem without major architectural changes. I would never actually use this in my own code.